# How to get a dropdown to activate 2 different python codes, flask / sql

Tags: python, mysql, flask, linker, dropdown

I'm currently trying to create a small SQL database.

I am fairly new to python, SQL, flask etc. so apologies if it is really simple.

So I have created most of my code (displayed at bottom), but I would like the two buttons: `id="admin_user_demote"` and `id="admin_user_promote"` to both pull their required information from the same 'dropdown (select)'.

I would like to know if this is possible and any help leading towards a solution would be greatly appreciated.

```
<form action="/admin_user." method="post">
    <select class="user_search_admin" type="text" name="user_search_admin" id="user_search_admin">
        {% for loginUser in loginUsers %}
            <option>{{ loginUser.username}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="admin_user" id="admin_user_promote" onclick="/admin_user.admin_user_promote" value="admin_user_promote"> 
        <b>Make Selected User an Admin</b>
    </button>
    <button type="submit" class="delete_user" id="admin_user_demote" onclick="/admin_user.admin_user_demote" value="admin_user_demote"> 
        <b>Make Selected User a regular user</b>
    </button>
</form>
```

python bit :

```
@auth.route('/admin_user', methods=['GET', 'Post'])

def admin_user_promote():
    bla bla bla 

def admin_user_demote():
    bla bla bla
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're super close, you just really need to give your submission buttons a 'name' so you can refer to their values when the form gets submitted, so lets call them both `action`:

```
<button name="action" type="submit" class="admin_user" id="admin_user_promote" onclick="/admin_user.admin_user_promote" value="admin_user_promote"> 
    <b>Make Selected User an Admin</b>
</button>
<button name="action" type="submit" class="delete_user" id="admin_user_demote" onclick="/admin_user.admin_user_demote" value="admin_user_demote"> 
    <b>Make Selected User a regular user</b>
</button>
```

With a name set, you can then check on it's value:

```
@auth.route('/admin_user', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def example():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        action = request.form.get('action')
        selected_user = request.form.get('user_search_admin')

        if action == 'admin_user_promote':
            admin_user_promote(selected_user)
        elif action == 'admin_user_demote':
            admin_user_demote(selected_user)

    return render_template('example.html')
```

You'd need to change your `admin_user_promote` and `admin_user_demote` functions to accept the `selected_user` so you would have a reference to use within the function:

```
def admin_user_demote(user):
    #update database, etc etc with `user`
```

If you wanted to flash a message (lets say they get returned to the `home` page once a user is updated, and the `home` page looks for flashed messages) you might want to just add another function that returns a username-- e.g:

```
def resolve_username(user_id):
    # get the username from the database, etc.
    username = User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first()
    return username
```

Then adjust your view to match our new rules:

```
@auth.route('/admin_user', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def example():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        action = request.form.get('action')
        selected_user = request.form.get('user_search_admin')
        username = resolve_username(selected_user)

        if action == 'admin_user_promote':
            admin_user_promote(selected_user)
            flash('{} promoted'.format(username))
        elif action == 'admin_user_demote':
            admin_user_demote(selected_user)
            flash('{} demoted'.format(username))
        else:
            flash('Something odd happened!')

        return redirect(url_for('home'))

    return render_template('example.html')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, greatly appreciated and did the trick. Hate that it was something so simple *face-palm* but oh well. Another quick thing, if I wanted to create a flash like: flash(selected_user 'has been made an admin'), where the word 'selected_user' was replaced with the name of the user from : selected_user = request.form.get('user_search_admin'). Do you know how this is achieved?